# Сделать обновление кнопки

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

При нажатии на кнопку фильтр выводится окно сайдбара, где можно выбрать параметры фильтров, задать и отфильтровать. Но при закрытии окна (когда товар отфильтрован хоть по одному параметру), я не могу повторно нажать на кнопку без обновления страницы. Добавил скрипт обновления, все равно не работает.

```
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $('.btn').click(function(){setTimeout(function(){$(".btn").load("# .btn");}, 1000);});
            </script>
```

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'techmarket_wc_handheld_sidebar' ) ) {
    /**
     * Outputs WooCommerce Handheld Sidebar Toggle
     */
    function techmarket_wc_handheld_sidebar() {

        if( apply_filters( 'techmarket_has_handheld_sidebar', true ) ) {
            $handheld_sidebar_title = apply_filters( 'techmarket_handheld_sidebar_title', esc_html__( 'Filters', 'techmarket' ) );
            $handheld_sidebar_icon  = apply_filters( 'techmarket_handheld_sidebar_icon', 'fa fa-sliders' );
            ?><div class="handheld-sidebar-toggle">
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            $('.btn').click(function(){setTimeout(function(){$(".btn").load("# .btn");}, 1000);});
            </script>
            <button class="btn sidebar-toggler" type="button">
            <i class="<?php echo esc_attr( $handheld_sidebar_icon ); ?>"></i>
            <span><?php echo esc_html( $handheld_sidebar_title ); ?></span>
            </button>
            </div><?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Причем тут java? У вас даже php в коде используется и, кстати, почему самый последний тег <?php не закрыт?

Comment: @dred последний по файлу тег <?php закрывать не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в обработчике на нажатие на кнопку, так как `html` меняется динамически, вот этот селектор:

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
   // ваш код
})
```

нужно написать так

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
   // ваш код
});
```